# Creating a guessing game

Tags: java

I am following a mooc in which I have to create a guessing game. I kind of understand the problem but I have no clue how to fix it.

The problem is that for the method "loop" numberDrawn isn't a defined integer. But I define it in the main argument body where "loop" is placed so how come "loop" doesn't see that I defined it already.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingNumberGame {

    private static int drawNumber() {
        return new Random().nextInt(101);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int numberDrawn = drawNumber();

        if (numberDrawn > num) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");
            loop();
        } else if (numberDrawn < num) {
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");
            loop();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
        }
    }

    public static void loop() {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (numberDrawn > num) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");
            loop();
        } else if (numberDrawn < num) {
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");
            loop();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message when you have an issue; it can be a bit difficult to interpret a paraphrase.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol

         if (numberDrawn > num) {

      symbol:   variable numberDrawn
      location: class GuessingNumberGame

Comment: ^ That's because you're trying to access variables in the `main` method from a different method. See Blue Ice's answer; that's how you should do it. You don't need a recursive loop function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `numberDrawn` is local to `main()`, and is inaccessible from `loop()`. The variable cannot be used in `loop()` unless it is passed.

However, it seems to me like the second `loop()` function is unnecessary and will create recursive loops. I modified `main()` to work properly and contain a loop:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingNumberGame {

private static int drawNumber() {
    return new Random().nextInt(101);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");        
        int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        int numberDrawn = drawNumber();


        if (numberDrawn > num) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");

        }   else if (numberDrawn < num) { 
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");

        }   else {
            break;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I dont follow. What second loop function? loop is the name of the method i created to loop the program

Comment: It is not a function, but the `while(true)` loop that I made will run the number-guessing part until the correct answer is given.

Comment: Wow I cant believe it was this simple. I dont know why I was messing around with methods unnecessarily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you have defined your "**numberDrawn**" variable in a method ,variables defined in the method are local to the method. Just define your variable at variable declarations and make it **static**.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingNumberGame {


     static int numberDrawn=0;
    private static int drawNumber() {
        return new Random().nextInt(101);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        numberDrawn= drawNumber();

        if (numberDrawn > num) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");
            loop();
        } else if (numberDrawn < num) {
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");
            loop();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
        }
    }

    public static void loop() {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Guess a number: ");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if (numberDrawn > num) {
            System.out.println("The number is greater");
            loop();
        } else if (numberDrawn < num) {
            System.out.println("The number is lesser");
            loop();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because main() is also considered as a different method in Java and all the variables defined in main() is not accessible to external methods directly ie. loop() in your case. One solution is passing the variable numberdrawn as an argument to the method. Another is you can define the variable numberdrawn outside the main method.

Answer (score 0):

try this, declare ur variable at class level like this:

```
public class GuessingNumberGame {
    private static int numberDrawn;
```

in ur main();

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());//no change here
numberDrawn = drawNumber();//remove int keyword
```